# Passing a deque to a new pthread

Tags: c++, thread-safety, pthreads, deque

I have a block of code where I am inside a pthread (lets call this thread `a`), and I wish to spawn a new pthread (lets call this thread `b`). Thread `b` needs to be passed a deque and I have the following code:

```
void* process_thread_b(void* arg)
{              
  deque<string> *ptr = (deque<string>*)arg;
  cout << "Size -" << ptr->size() << endl;

  deque<string>::iterator it;
  for(it = ptr->begin(); it != ptr->end(); it++)
  {
    cout <<(*it) << endl;
  }
}
```

The above code is thread `b's` code. It is passed a deque and it prints out the size correctly. The moment I try printing out any of it's elements, I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
 what():  std::bad_alloc
Abort (core dumped)
```

When I am spawning the pthread, I use the below code...

```
 deque<string> myDeque;

 // Add strings to deque here...

 pthread_t dispatchCommands;
 pthread_create(&dispatchCommands, NULL, &process_thread_b, (void*)&myDeque);
```

The bottom code takes place in thread `a`. Why is it when I try to print out an element of the deque, I am getting an error, yet I can get it's size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pthread_create` will return long before your thread function begins to execute. Your `deque` will have been destroyed long ago. You need to create it on the heap.

Comment: Or make sure the master does not exit the current scope (or the deque is in a scope that is not exited before the thread terminates). (both a more common solution).

Comment: A good idiom to use when you need to pass an object to a thread that will "own" it is to allocate it using `new`, pass a pointer to it to the thread's start function, and have the thread `delete` it when it's done. You can have the thread's start function do all the work, like this: `void* MyThreadFunction(void *foo) { reinterpret_cast<Bar*>(foo); foo->RealWorkFunction(); delete foo; return NULL; }`

Comment: A good idiom to use when writing multithreaded apps is to dynamically allocate everything. There is, sadly, a lot of unqualified 'always allocate on the stack, don't use new()' advice, both on this site and the net generally. Developers follow this advice and end up with startup crashes, (like OP), shutdown problems when the threads try to access static objects that the crt has destructed, and sundry problems in between.

Comment: @MartinJames: That's very incorrect. Not using `new` doesn't mean "Don't dynamically allocate", it means "Don't expose yourself to the hideous exception and memory unsafety of raw `new`", which are two totally different things.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are trying to cast the reference to the deck to a void*, try this:

```
 deque<string> * myDeque = new deque<string>();
```

then use -> to access its functions.

Then you can  cast myDeque straight to a void pointer and it will remain initialised.

ie. :

```
 (void*)myDeque
```

Hope this helps.